# Insufficient Privileges as System Administrator on Opportunity

Tags: security, opportunity, sharing

I am the System Administrator (Standard Profile) and receiving Insufficient Privileges error when trying to access Opportunity fields.

> "Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. "

I am doing same operations on "Lead" and it works fine as I required, but don't know what does go wrong with the "Opportunity".

I have seen "View All = True" which is by default for the System Administrator profile.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fields"? Are you trying to view an Opportunity? Modify it? standard page layout or some visualforce page? If you're saving something / submitting a form - could it be going to triggers? Maybe there's some managed package that you're not licensed to use, check debug log maybe?

Comment: I am having one VF page where I have picklist with the all fields of opportunity into it, when I select field from the picklist to read/update values after clicking on Save, it gives me this error message.  I have tried "Debug Logs" it doesn't even go inside the "saveMethod" method. No any triggers or Validation rules are there.

Comment: But, Yes I have created Managed Beta Package, since profile is System Administrator, do this (Managed Package License) have to cause something ?

Comment: Weird. Does the Profile have access that VF page and maybe also Apex class? Check the field permissions on Opportunity too.

Comment: Yes it is Weird, And I have checked all permissions on Opp, VF and Controller too, even I gone through all User Permission Sets. I dont know why this thing is not working with "Opportunity" where as its very fine with "Lead". with same level of access and permissions.

Comment: Please make sure that the version settings of visualforce page and its controller/extension is same.

Comment: @AmitBangad : please put that as a Answer, Its truly important and tricky one which will surly help others. ( I am also having bounty of 50 points :P but its worth it). Thanks

Comment: Did it, up-vote if it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since all the areas are already explored , here is a tricky and important suggestion - 
**Please make sure that the version settings of visualforce page and its controller/extension is same.**

Hope this helps!